# Setting up golang to work with Python in GitHub

Tags: github, go

I have a GitHub repo with some python code and some text files. However, I want to add some Golang code to my project.

So basically my issue is that I'm confused on where to set my GOPATH so I can work with Go source files in the same place that I work on python files. Do I set my GOPATH to my repo path, then setup the \src\github.com\user\ directory and put my Go code there? Do I put Grandzam where user is, or leave it alone because someone else is working with me on the repo?

https://golang.org/doc/install Test your installation is what I am confused about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend setting up an environment consistent with the recommendations in the "[Organizing your code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)" section of the language documentation.

First, choose a top level directory (I tend to use `~/devel`), and set the value of your GOPATH environment var to that location, and add the GOPATH/bin dir to your path.  Put it in your the appropriate session startup file (`~/.bash_profile` or similar).  In my case, I would put these lines in that file:

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/devel
export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$PATH
```

Quoting from the documentation:

To give you an idea of how a workspace looks in practice, here's an example:

```
bin/
    hello                          # command executable
    outyet                         # command executable
pkg/
    linux_amd64/
        github.com/golang/example/
            stringutil.a           # package object
src/
    github.com/golang/example/
        .git/                      # Git repository metadata
    hello/
        hello.go               # command source
    outyet/
        main.go                # command source
        main_test.go           # test source
    stringutil/
        reverse.go             # package source
        reverse_test.go        # test source
    golang.org/x/image/
        .git/                      # Git repository metadata
    bmp/
        reader.go              # package source
        writer.go              # package source
    ... (many more repositories and packages omitted) ...
```

Next, clone your git repo into the appropriate path under the $GOPATH/src tree.  In my case it would be `$GOPATH/src/github.com/user/repo`.

Now you should be all set to work on both go and python code without much trouble.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to set up my project this way now.